# BelongToMany with Sequelize table not associated

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, sequelize.js

I tried to associate 2 tables through a new one that I have already created in mySql. Then I can get needed data from API. The 2 tables to link with a new one are user and country. A user can visit many countries. A country can be visited by many users.

Here is my model User.js :

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/db.js')
const Country = require('./Country')

const User = db.sequelize.define('user', 
{
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    admin: {
        type: Sequelize.TINYINT
    }
},
{
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,       
});
User.associate = () => {
    User.belongsToMany(Country, {
        through: 'Country_user',
        as: 'country',
        foreignKey: 'id_user'
    });
};

module.exports = User
```

Then here is my model Country.js :

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/db.js')
const User = require('./User')

const Country = db.sequelize.define('country', 
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        code: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER        
        },
        alpha2: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        alpha3: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        name_en: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        name_fr: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });
    Country.associate = () => {
      Country.belongsToMany(User, {
        through: 'Country_user',
        as: 'user',
        foreignKey: 'id_country'
      });
    };

module.exports = Country;
```

Here is my model Country_user.js :

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/db.js')

const Country_user = db.sequelize.define('country_user', {
    id_user: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'User',
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    id_country: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'Country',
            key: 'id'
        }
      }
    });

module.exports = Country_user
```

And finally, here is my query to get data that I need :

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
const User = require('../../models/User')
const Country = require('../../models/Country')

    router.get('/user', function(req, res, next){
        User.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: Country,
                as: 'country',
                attributes: ['id', 'name_fr'],
                through: { attributes: [] }
            }]
        })
            .then(user => {
                res.json(user)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.send('error: ' + err)
            })
    })

    module.exports = router
```

I would like that the ORM will not create new fields in database. I already created them. I just want to link theses foreign keys to right table in ORM in order that I can easily get my data.

When I tried to user the route /user, I get this from POSTMAN :

error: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: country is not associated to user!

Edit: The file db.js is built like this :

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = {}
const sequelize = new Sequelize('travel_memories', 'root', '', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: 3306
})

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your models through something like this?

```
Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
    // console.log(models[modelName]);
    models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});
```

To actually establish the associations?? Just adding the belongsToMany association logic in Country and User is not enough

I have an index file in my models directory that does something like this, i'll modify it a bit for you, you'll need to replace the "path_to" statements to whatever your proper path is....

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../../helpers/db';

const models = {
  Country: sequelize.import('./path_to_country'),
  User: sequelize.import('./path_to_user'),
  CountryUserJoin: sequelize.import('./path_to_join')      
};

Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
    // console.log(models[modelName]);
    models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});

models.sequelize = sequelize;
models.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default models;
```

Comment: Hello, I really don't understand what you mean. Where should I write this in my code?

Comment: I added some code above that i use... you need to run your models through something like this before you use them

Comment: Hello, I think I still don't understand how I can do that. See the edit, that's how my application is built. Thanks.

Comment: Console says : sequelize.import is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = {}
const sequelize = new Sequelize('travel_memories', 'root', '', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: 3306
})

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

const models = {
  Country: sequelize.import('../../models/Country'),
  User: sequelize.import('../../models/User'),
  CountryUserJoin: sequelize.import('../../models/Country_user')      
};

Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
// console.log(models[modelName]);
models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

Comment: the path to the models in comet models = may not be exactly right because I don’t know your structure, so you might have to change this... but it will make the model associations for you... just declaring them in your models is not enough

Comment: Tell me if it still says sequelize import is not a function, then I’d have to compare our sequelize versions and what other things I may have added

Comment: I have no problem with sequelize.import. But, When I write in my models something like db.sequelize.define(....), the console says "Cannot read property 'define' of undefined. So the fact that I write this loop transform the db object? What to write then?

Comment: Or just maybe because I am calling for my models when I write sequelize.import(...path), and my models are beginning with db.sequelize.define when db is not exported.

Comment: Yes, at the point where you are calling that, it is just sequelize, you have not exported it yet

Comment: So could you give me a bit help with how I should write my models in order to avoid this db.sequelize.define and just use sequelize.define. Because, if I just write sequelize.define, it says "sequelize is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

This is how i wrote mine in it's own js file:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Country = sequelize.define('loc_countries', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    abbr2: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    abbr3: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'loc_countries',
  });

  Country.associate = function (models) {
    models.Country.hasMany(models.ProvinceState, { as: 'ProvStates', foreignKey: 'loc_countries_id' });
  };

  return Country;
};
```

Comment: OK, I changed my models. I would like to know how now I can query my database. Because simple query when i'm calling User.findAll, the console says User.findAll is not a function. And it's logical because the database is not linked to models... How should I do that please? Thanks again for your precious help !

Comment: When it comes to calling the query you should be using the db.sequelize instance of your models that you are passing around

Comment: Ok, so I did User(db, Sequelize.DataTypes).findAll({}). Thank you so much for explanations. I am going to try if tables are correctly associated now.

Comment: Where does 'models' comes from? When you call models.Country. Because for me it doesn't work : look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930091/how-to-build-model-with-sequelize-for-belong-to-many-association

Comment: You have a const called models in your code when you are exporting db but you didn’t do anything with it... you declare it and set it up, but then just exported db.... your setup is way different than mine but i don’t reference the db directly in my models.. instead of exporting db there I actually add it to the models object like models.sequelize = sequelize... or in your case models.db = db and then I export models... just import models instead of db and use models.User or models.Country to make your queries.. if you need to reference db at any point then it would be available as models.db